# Why does a runnable JAR exported from Eclipse continue to use old configuration settings?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am exporting a runnable JAR from Eclipse.  When run, it reads in a configuration file and based on this configuration file opens other files also for configuration purposes.  However, when I move this JAR to another location it continues to try to use the values in the old configuration file, even though a new configuration file is present.  Why does it do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the file is included in the Eclipse build path, so when it gets exported that file is built with the JAR.  Then, regardless of whatever path is given for the configuration file on the command line, the JAR will use the file that was already packaged inside of itself.  (This was my problem.  Removing it from the build path resolved the issue.)